# DataTables rowGroup loses its class after filtering

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to apply some styling to the groupped rows. So

```
rowGroup: {
        dataSrc: 'team',
        className: 'rowGroup1'
    },

"initComplete": function (settings, json) {
    $(".rowGroup1").children().css("text-transform", "uppercase");
}
```

Works fine for the initial draw of the datatable, but if I search and filter some of the data, the `rowGroup` rows are still there groupped OK, but the style is gone.

How do I reapply the class to the groupped rows?

**EDIT**

I've tried drawCallback to no success, maybe it's being used wrong.

```
  "drawCallback": function (settings) {
        $(".rowGroup1").children().css("text-transform", "uppercase");
  }
```

**EDIT 2**

Got it after picking up an idea while checking a problem with `scroller` in the DT forum, [endRender](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowGroup.endRender) had to be used inside `rowGroup` brackets.

```
endRender: function (rows, group) {
            $(".rowGroup1").children().css("text-transform", "uppercase");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In DataTable, the initComplete function is only fired the first time that DataTable is loaded.
You must use drawCallback instead to reapply the class to your rows.
https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback

Comment: I've tried it but didn't manage to make it work. Added the piece of code I've used.